# Can I get the version of i4jruntime.jar that was used to launch an application from within the application?

Tags: install4j

I would like to log which version of install4j has just launched my application for diagnostic purposes in the future when a user contacts us for help with a problem.

I know i4jruntime.jar is put in the application's classpath by the install4j launcher but can't see a documented way to find which version of install4j is being used.

Answer (score 1):

As of 7.0.11, there is no good way to do so. In the upcoming 8.0 release, you will be able to call

```
Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.install4jVersion")
```

in your code.